# Custom module is not appearing in magento admin roles page for webservices

Tags: magento-enterprise, api

Actually I creaed custom module helloworld. I created all specified files as specified in documentation of magento.But where the problem is encounter, Actullly my code is as follows.
Plz I am new to this domain can any body help where I did the wrong I need to publish the custom webservice method but iam not getting this module name in the list to give role to user.

Test
  [image]

Test is Package name and my indexController.php code is

```
<?php
class Test_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    /*     * this method privides default action.     */
    public function indexAction()
    {        /*         * Initialization of Mage_Core_Model_Layout model         */
        echo 'Hi this is Custom Module' . '</br>';
        /*/*         * Initialization of Mage_Core_Model_Layout model         */
       // $this->loadLayout();         /*         * Building page according to layout confuration         */
        //$this->renderLayout();
    }
}
?>
```

ANd my Adminhtml.xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <helloworld_mod translate="title" module="helloworld">
                <title>Store Hello World Module Section</title>
            </helloworld_mod>
        </menu>

        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <helloworld_mod translate="title" module="helloworld">
                            <title>Store Hello World Module Section</title>
                        </helloworld_mod>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
 </config>
```

and my api.xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api>
        <resources>
            <acl>
                <helloworld_category translate="title" module="helloworld">
                    <model>helloworld/category_api</model>
                    <methods>
                        <hello translate="title" module="helloworld">
                        </hello>
                    </methods>
                    <faults>
                        <data_invalid>
                            <code> 100 </code>
                            <message>Invalid data</message>
                        </data_invalid>
                    </faults>
                </helloworld_category>
            </acl>
        </resources>
        <V2>
            <resources_function_prefix>
                <helloworld> hello</helloworld>
            </resources_function_prefix>
        </V2>

        <resources_alias>
            <helloworld>helloworld_category</helloworld>
        </resources_alias>

    </api>
</config>
```

and my cofig.xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <test_helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </test_helloworld>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>

            <helloworld>

                <use>standard</use>

                <args>

                    <module>test_helloworld</module>

                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>

                </args>

            </helloworld>

        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>

         <helpers>
            <helloworld>
                <class>test_telloworld_Helper</class>
            </helloworld>
        </helpers>

        <adminhtml>
            <!--<menu>
                <Helloworld translate="title" module="Helloworld">
                    <title>Blacklist</title>
                    <sort_order>71</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <items translate="title" module="blacklist">
                            <title>Manage Items</title>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            <action>blacklist/adminhtml_blacklist</action>
                        </items>
                    </children>
                </Helloworld>
            </menu>-->

            <acl>
                <resources>
                    <admin>
                        <children>

                            <helloworld>
                                <title>Store Hello World Module Section</title>
                            </helloworld>

                        </children>
                    </admin>
                </resources>
            </acl>
        </adminhtml>

    </global>
</config>
```

and my system.xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <helloconfig translate="label" module="Helloworld">
            <label>Hello Config</label>
            <sort_order>99999</sort_order>
        </helloconfig>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <helloworld_options translate="label" module="Helloworld">
            <label>Hello World Config Options</label>
            <tab>helloconfig</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        </helloworld_options>
    </sections>
</config>
```

and wsdl.xm code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </schema>
    </types>
    <message name="helloRequest">
        <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="msg" type="xsd:string" />
    </message>
    <message name="helloResponse">
        <part name="result" type="xsd:string" />
    </message>
    <portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <operation name="hello">
            <documentation>HelloWorld msg</documentation>
            <input message="typens:helloRequest" />
            <output message="typens:helloResponse" />
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <operation name="hello">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
            <input>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
</definitions>
```

And my Data.php code is

```
<?php
class Test_Helloworld_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

And my V2.php code is

```
<?php
class Test_Helloworld_Model_category_Api_V2 extends Test_Helloworld_Model_category_Api
{
}
```

And my Api.php code is

```
<?php
class Test_Helloworld_Model_category_Api extends Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract
{

    public function hello($sessionId,$msg)
    {
        $result = 'this is from custom module'.$msg ;
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Pease I am new to this domain can any body help where I did the wrong I need to publish the custom webservice method but I am not getting this module name in the list to give role to user.

Answer (score 1):

To get the information appearing in the webserives section you will need to make the following changes.

1. Move the switch the acl and resources nodes it should be acl->resources,
2. Add a title node inside the helloworld_category section,

The file should looks as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <helloworld_category translate="title" module="helloworld">
                    <title>Hello World</title>
                    <model>helloworld/category_api</model>
                    <methods>
                        <hello translate="title" module="helloworld">
                        </hello>
                    </methods>
                    <faults>
                        <data_invalid>
                            <code> 100 </code>
                            <message>Invalid data</message>
                        </data_invalid>
                    </faults>
                </helloworld_category>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <V2>
            <resources_function_prefix>
                <helloworld> hello</helloworld>
            </resources_function_prefix>
        </V2>

        <resources_alias>
            <helloworld>helloworld_category</helloworld>
        </resources_alias>
    </api>
</config>
```

One final comment is to be careful with the cases in magento I notice that your controllers directory starts uppercase where it should be lowercase. Also in your system.xml you are using module="Helloworld" where it should be lowercase.